# 3D FPS Camera in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

So I've got a basic FPS camera working which can move around the 3D space. Having trouble with physics but thats not why I'm here!

So the code below creates a scenegraph which contains torus model objects, and I can move around in the space using the keys and mouse movement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GLM/glm.hpp>
#include <GLM/gtx/transform.hpp>

void errorCallbackGLFW(int error, const char* description);
void hintsGLFW();
void endProgram();
void render(double currentTime);
void update(double currentTime);
void setupRender();
void startup();
void onResizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h);
void onKeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
void onMouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods);
void onMouseMoveCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double x, double y);
void debugGL();
static void APIENTRY openGLDebugCallback(GLenum source,
    GLenum type,
    GLuint id,
    GLenum severity,
    GLsizei length,
    const GLchar* message,
    const GLvoid* userParam);
string readShader(string name);
void checkErrorShader(GLuint shader);
void readObj(string name);

// VARIABLES
GLFWwindow* window;
int windowWidth = 640;
int windowHeight = 480;
bool running = true;

GLuint program;
GLuint vao;
GLuint buffer[2];
GLint mv_location;
GLint proj_location;
float aspect;
glm::mat4 proj_matrix;
float angleX = 0.0f;
float angleY = 0.0f;
float disp = 0.0;
float fovy = 45.0f;
glm::vec3 cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
bool keyStatus[1024];
GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastTime = 0.0f;

// FPS camera variables
GLfloat yaw = -90.0f; // init pointing to inside
GLfloat pitch = 0.0f; // start centered
GLfloat lastX = windowWidth / 2.0f; // start middle screen
GLfloat lastY = windowHeight / 2.0f; // start middle screen
bool firstMouse = true;

// OBJ Variables
std::vector<glm::vec3> out_vertices;
std::vector<glm::vec2> out_uvs;
std::vector<glm::vec3> out_normals;

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) { // Checking for GLFW
        cout << "Could not initialise GLFW...";
        return 0;
    }

    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallbackGLFW); // Setup a function to catch and display all GLFW errors.

    hintsGLFW(); // Setup glfw with various hints.

                 // Start a window using GLFW
    string title = "Snowglobe Project";
    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    windowWidth = mode->width;
    windowHeight = mode->height;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, title.c_str(), glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
    //window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, title.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) { // Window or OpenGL context creation failed
        cout << "Could not initialise GLFW...";
        endProgram();
        return 0;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // making the OpenGL context current

                                    // Start GLEW (note: always initialise GLEW after creating your window context.)
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; // hack: catching them all - forcing newest debug callback (glDebugMessageCallback)
    GLenum errGLEW = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != errGLEW) { // Problems starting GLEW?
        cout << "Could not initialise GLEW...";
        endProgram();
        return 0;
    }

    debugGL(); // Setup callback to catch openGL errors.

               // Setup all the message loop callbacks.
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, onResizeCallback); // Set callback for resize
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, onKeyCallback); // Set Callback for keys
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, onMouseButtonCallback); // Set callback for mouse click
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, onMouseMoveCallback); // Set callback for mouse move
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED); // Set mouse cursor FPS.

    setupRender(); // setup some render variables.
    startup(); // Setup all necessary information for startup (aka. load texture, shaders, models, etc).

    do { // run until the window is closed

        double currentTime = glfwGetTime(); // retrieve timelapse
        deltaTime = (float)currentTime - lastTime; // Calculate delta time
        lastTime = (float)currentTime; // Save for next frame calculations.
        glfwPollEvents(); // poll callbacks
        update(currentTime); // update (physics, animation, structures, etc)
        render(currentTime); // call render function.

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap buffers (avoid flickering and tearing)

        running &= (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_RELEASE); // exit if escape key pressed
        running &= (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) != GL_TRUE);
    } while (running);

    endProgram(); // Close and clean everything up...

    cout << "\nPress any key to continue...\n";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get(); // delay closing console to read debugging errors.

    return 0;
}

void errorCallbackGLFW(int error, const char* description) {
    cout << "Error GLFW: " << description << "\n";
}

void hintsGLFW() {
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE); // Create context in debug mode - for debug message callback
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
}

void endProgram()
{
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // destroys window handler
    glfwTerminate(); // destroys all windows and releases resources.
}

void setupRender() {
    glfwSwapInterval(1); // Ony render when synced (V SYNC)

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STEREO, GL_FALSE);
}

void startup() {
    string vs_text = readShader("vs.glsl");
    const char* vs_source = vs_text.c_str();

    string fs_text = readShader("fs.glsl");
    static const char* fs_source2 = fs_text.c_str();

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);
    checkErrorShader(vs);

    program = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fs_source2, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);
    checkErrorShader(fs);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    readObj("torus.obj");

    mv_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mv_matrix");
    proj_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "proj_matrix");

    // Calculate proj_matrix for the first time.
    aspect = (float)windowWidth / (float)windowHeight;
    proj_matrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fovy), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    //OPENGL 4.5 VERSION
    glCreateBuffers(2, buffer); // Create a new buffer

                                // Store the vertices
    glNamedBufferStorage(buffer[0], // Set data store
        out_vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3),
        &out_vertices[0],
        GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]); // Bind Buffer

                                              // Store the colours
    glNamedBufferStorage(buffer[1], // Set data store
        out_normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3),
        &out_normals[0],
        GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[1]); // Bind Buffer

    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao); // Create Vertex Array Object
                                   // Bind vertex position buffer to the vao
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, // Vertex array object
        0, // First vertex buffer binding
        buffer[0], // Buffer object
        0, // Start from the beginning
        sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 // size of vertex
    );

    // Specify the format for it
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, // Vertex array object
        0, // First attribute
        3, // Number of components
        GL_FLOAT, // Using floats
        GL_FALSE, // Normalised
        0 // First element of the vertex
    );

    // Bind vertex colour buffer to the vao
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, // Vertex array object
        1, // First vertex buffer binding
        buffer[1], // Buffer object
        0, // Start from the beginning
        sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 // size of vertex colour
    );

    // Specify the format for it
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, // Vertex array object
        1, // Second attribute
        3, // Number of components
        GL_FLOAT, // Using floats
        GL_FALSE, // Normalised
        0 // First element of the vertex
    );

    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 0); // Enable Vertex Array Attribute
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 1); // Enable Vertex Array Attribute

    glBindVertexArray(vao); // Bind VertexArrayObject

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
}

void update(double currentTime) {
    // calculate movement
    GLfloat cameraSpeed = 1.0f * deltaTime;
    if (keyStatus[GLFW_KEY_W])
        cameraPosition += cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
    if (keyStatus[GLFW_KEY_S])
        cameraPosition -= cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
    if (keyStatus[GLFW_KEY_A])
        cameraPosition -= glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, cameraUp)) * cameraSpeed;
    if (keyStatus[GLFW_KEY_D])
        cameraPosition += glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, cameraUp)) * cameraSpeed;

    //Sprint-like movement and FOV with LSHIFT
    if (keyStatus[GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL]) {
        int fovModifier = 0.25f;

        fovy += fovModifier;
        if (fovy >= 1.0f && fovy <= 10.0f)
            fovy -= (float)fovModifier;
        if (fovy <= 1.0f)
            fovy = 1.0f;
        if (fovy >= 45.0f)
            fovy = 45.0f;
        proj_matrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fovy), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    }
}

void render(double currentTime) {
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

    // Clear colour buffer
    static const GLfloat silver[] = { 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, silver);

    // Clear Deep buffer
    static const GLfloat one = 1.0f;
    glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, &one);

    glUseProgram(program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, &proj_matrix[0][0]);

    glm::vec3 modelPositions[] = {
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.0f, 1.0f, -0.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.5f, -0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f),
        glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f),
        glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f),
        glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f),
        glm::vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f),
    };

    glm::vec3 modelRotations[] = {
        glm::vec3(30.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(20.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(30.0f, 40.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(20.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(40.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(70.0f, 60.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(80.0f, 60.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(10.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(70.0f, 30.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(50.0f, 40.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(60.0f, 80.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(70.0f, 80.0f, 0.0f),
    };

    glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(cameraPosition, // eye
        cameraPosition + cameraFront, // centre
        cameraUp); // up

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, disp));
        modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, modelPositions[i]);
        modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, angleX + modelRotations[i].x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, angleY + modelRotations[i].y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

        glm::mat4 mv_matrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

        glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, GL_FALSE, &mv_matrix[0][0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, out_vertices.size());
    }
}

void onResizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h) {
    windowWidth = w;
    windowHeight = h;

    aspect = (float)w / (float)h;
    proj_matrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fovy), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
}

void onKeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
        keyStatus[key] = true;
    else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        keyStatus[key] = false;

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_LEFT)
        angleY += 0.05f;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_RIGHT)
        angleY -= 0.05f;

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_UP)
        angleX += 0.05f;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_DOWN)
        angleX -= 0.05f;

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_KP_ADD)
        disp += 0.10f;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_KP_SUBTRACT)
        disp -= 0.10f;
}

void onMouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
}

void onMouseMoveCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double x, double y)
{
    int mouseX = static_cast<int>(x);
    int mouseY = static_cast<int>(y);

    if (firstMouse) {
        lastX = (float)mouseX;
        lastY = (float)mouseY;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    GLfloat xoffset = mouseX - lastX;
    GLfloat yoffset = lastY - mouseY; // Reversed
    lastX = (float)mouseX;
    lastY = (float)mouseY;

    GLfloat sensitivity = 0.05f;
    xoffset *= sensitivity;
    yoffset *= sensitivity;

    yaw += xoffset;
    pitch += yoffset;

    // check for pitch out of bounds otherwise screen gets flipped
    if (pitch > 89.0f)
        pitch = 89.0f;
    if (pitch < -89.0f)
        pitch = -89.0f;

    glm::vec3 front;
    front.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.z = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));

    cameraFront = glm::normalize(front);
}

void debugGL()
{
    //Output some debugging information
    cout << "VENDOR: " << (char*)glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << endl;
    cout << "VERSION: " << (char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
    cout << "RENDERER: " << (char*)glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << endl;

    // Enable Opengl Debug
    //glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
    glDebugMessageCallback((GLDEBUGPROC)openGLDebugCallback, nullptr);
    glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, NULL, true);
}

static void APIENTRY openGLDebugCallback(GLenum source,
    GLenum type,
    GLuint id,
    GLenum severity,
    GLsizei length,
    const GLchar* message,
    const GLvoid* userParam)
{

    cout << "---------------------opengl-callback------------" << endl;
    cout << "Message: " << message << endl;
    cout << "type: ";
    switch (type) {
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR:
        cout << "ERROR";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR:
        cout << "DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR:
        cout << "UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PORTABILITY:
        cout << "PORTABILITY";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE:
        cout << "PERFORMANCE";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER:
        cout << "OTHER";
        break;
    }
    cout << " --- ";

    cout << "id: " << id << " --- ";
    cout << "severity: ";
    switch (severity) {
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW:
        cout << "LOW";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM:
        cout << "MEDIUM";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH:
        cout << "HIGH";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_NOTIFICATION:
        cout << "NOTIFICATION";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
}

string readShader(string name)
{
    string vs_text;
    std::ifstream vs_file(name);

    string vs_line;
    if (vs_file.is_open()) {

        while (getline(vs_file, vs_line)) {
            vs_text += vs_line;
            vs_text += '\n';
        }
        vs_file.close();
    }
    return vs_text;
}

void checkErrorShader(GLuint shader)
{
    // Get log lenght
    GLint maxLength;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

    // Init a string for it
    std::vector<GLchar> errorLog(maxLength);

    if (maxLength > 1) {
        // Get the log file
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);

        cout << "--------------Shader compilation error-------------\n";
        cout << errorLog.data();
    }
}

void readObj(string name)
{
    cout << "Loading model " << name << "\n";

    std::vector<unsigned int> vertexIndices, uvIndices, normalIndices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> obj_vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> obj_uvs;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> obj_normals;

    std::ifstream dataFile(name);

    string rawData; // store the raw data.
    int countLines = 0;
    if (dataFile.is_open()) {
        string dataLineRaw;
        while (getline(dataFile, dataLineRaw)) {
            rawData += dataLineRaw;
            rawData += "\n";
            countLines++;
        }
        dataFile.close();
    }

    cout << "Finished reading model file " << name << "\n";

    istringstream rawDataStream(rawData);
    string dataLine;
    int linesDone = 0;
    while (std::getline(rawDataStream, dataLine)) {
        if (dataLine.find("v ") != string::npos) { // does this line have a vector?
            glm::vec3 vertex;

            int foundStart = dataLine.find(" ");
            int foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            vertex.x = stof(dataLine.substr(foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart));

            foundStart = foundEnd;
            foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            vertex.y = stof(dataLine.substr(foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart));

            foundStart = foundEnd;
            foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            vertex.z = stof(dataLine.substr(foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart));

            obj_vertices.push_back(vertex);
        }
        else if (dataLine.find("vt ") != string::npos) { // does this line have a uv coordinates?
            glm::vec2 uv;

            int foundStart = dataLine.find(" ");
            int foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            uv.x = stof(dataLine.substr(foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart));

            foundStart = foundEnd;
            foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            uv.y = stof(dataLine.substr(foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart));

            obj_uvs.push_back(uv);
        }
        else if (dataLine.find("vn ") != string::npos) { // does this line have a normal coordinates?
            glm::vec3 normal;

            int foundStart = dataLine.find(" ");
            int foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            normal.x = stof(dataLine.substr(foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart));

            foundStart = foundEnd;
            foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            normal.y = stof(dataLine.substr(foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart));

            foundStart = foundEnd;
            foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            normal.z = stof(dataLine.substr(foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart));

            obj_normals.push_back(normal);
        }
        else if (dataLine.find("f ") != string::npos) { // does this line defines a triangle face?
            string parts[3];

            int foundStart = dataLine.find(" ");
            int foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            parts[0] = dataLine.substr(foundStart + 1, foundEnd - foundStart - 1);

            foundStart = foundEnd;
            foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            parts[1] = dataLine.substr(foundStart + 1, foundEnd - foundStart - 1);

            foundStart = foundEnd;
            foundEnd = dataLine.find(" ", foundStart + 1);
            parts[2] = dataLine.substr(foundStart + 1, foundEnd - foundStart - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // for each part

                vertexIndices.push_back(stoul(parts[i].substr(0, parts[i].find("/"))));

                int firstSlash = parts[i].find("/");
                int secondSlash = parts[i].find("/", firstSlash + 1);

                if (firstSlash != (secondSlash + 1)) { // there is texture coordinates.
                                                       // add code for my texture coordintes here.
                }

                normalIndices.push_back(stoul(parts[i].substr(secondSlash + 1)));
            }
        }

        linesDone++;

        if (linesDone % 50000 == 0) {
            cout << "Parsed " << linesDone << " of " << countLines << " from model...\n";
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexIndices.size(); i += 3) {
        out_vertices.push_back(obj_vertices[vertexIndices[i + 2] - 1]);
        out_normals.push_back(obj_normals[normalIndices[i + 2] - 1]);

        out_vertices.push_back(obj_vertices[vertexIndices[i + 1] - 1]);
        out_normals.push_back(obj_normals[normalIndices[i + 1] - 1]);

        out_vertices.push_back(obj_vertices[vertexIndices[i] - 1]);
        out_normals.push_back(obj_normals[normalIndices[i] - 1]);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there were any improvements that could be made to make the code more modular and efficient!

**Also:** I tried using a different model which is bigger and a little more complex and the program just crashes when I try to render two of them. It is a simple pacman model i found online, it doesnt crash when i render one in the for loop but does when its greater than 1!

The model I used was a simple torus shape exported from blender and the fragment and vertex shaders I am using are here:

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 430 core

out vec4 color;

in VS_OUT
{
    vec4 color;
} fs_in;

void main(void)
{
    color = fs_in.color;
}
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;

out VS_OUT
{
    vec4 color;
} vs_out;

uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;
    vs_out.color = color;
}
```

Comment: Serious question: Why did you choose C++ over C for this project? I know libraries like OpenGL encourage this style, but If `std::string`, `std::vector` and streams are the only parts of C++ you actually use, you might be better off with just plain C...

Comment: @hoffmale I'm already started just using C++ because of its modularity in OOP compared to C. I posted this code to see if i could make it better in terms of efficiency as well as aesthetically with headers etc to kind of separate out the main file. As well as all that, see how I could improve the code in general